# Facebook - How to know if a user uses an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cant' find the right API call to know if a user has added an app? Any idea on how to do this or get the app users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the App users, you can store new users in your database with their ID right after authorizing. You can use the "Deauthorize Callback URL" field in the settings to check for users who deauthorized your App and remove them from your database.